# How can I know using GDataXML if a node exists in the xml string

Tags: ios, gdataxml

On my iOS app I am trying to find out if a node exists or not in the XML data.
I am trying to use

`+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementWithName:(NSString *)name` 
expecting it will return a nil if the node is not present but it does not seem to work.

One option is to convert the XML string into a dictionary and search for the key. But is there a  way to skip the Dictionary conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by using this

```
GDataXMLElement *abc = (GDataXMLElement *)parentNode;
NSArray *tempArray = [abc elementsForName:childNode ];
return [tempArray count];
```

Please let me know if there are any other ways of doing this.